# Allow weekdays in Database with trigger in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Hey, I would like to insert date values in my Database but i want Weekdays only to be acceptable!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JOB_VACANCY_DATE_DEADLINE_TRG
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF DATE_DEADLINE ON JOB_VACANCY FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF TRUNC(DATEPART(DW,:NEW.DATE_DEADLINE)) = 1 OR TRUNC(DATEPART(DW,:NEW.DATE_DEADLINE)) = 7 THEN
    /* Issue error code (ORA-20000) and message */
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Not allowed, ONLY WEEKDAYS');
    END IF;
END;
```

I got the error I have to declare DATEPART OR DATENAME!

Comment: What about holidays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no need to use DATEPART (if that's even a function in your oracle) and you probably don't want to use TRUNC either, as that rounds a date down to the nearest unit specified but it keeps the date element rounded to, so it's not just "Saturday" - it's Saturday the 2nd Dec 2017 or whatever

You probably should just do:

```
IF (TO_CHAR(yourdate, 'fmDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH') IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') )
  RAISE...
```

It's a lot more readable/self documenting than using trunc. I put the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE parameter in to ensure the code still works if run on an oracle whose language settings aren't English. You should note that using TO_CHAR with the D format specifier (returns a number between 1 and 7) are not immune to language variations either , as some locales do not consider Sunday to be 1 (the start of the week)

Comment: The format model should be `fmDAY` - otherwise `TO_CHAR` pads the output with spaces so it won't match `SATURDAY` or `SUNDAY`.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey; wouldn't have happened if I'd used DY / 3 letters - that's what I get for making code more self documenting, but not using oracle regularly enough to remember FMxxx!

Answer (score 1):

`datepart` ins't an Oracle function (it is a valid SQL Server function though!).

Instead, you could use the [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) function to extract the day of the week:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JOB_VACANCY_DATE_DEADLINE_TRG
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF DATE_DEADLINE ON JOB_VACANCY FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF TO_CHAR(:NEW.DATE_DEADLINE, 'D') IN (1, 7) THEN
        /* Issue error code (ORA-20000) and message */
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Not allowed, ONLY WEEKDAYS');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still accept weekend days i only want Week days Mon-Friday otherwise to appear the error message

Comment: This code has a bug. See the final comment in my answer